# Detect dirty rectangles in WPF/Direct3D surfaces?

Tags: c++, wpf, hook, screenshot, direct3d

I am experimenting with a remote screen mechanism, where I am pushing updated screen caps to clients (browsers). I have successfully implemented Win32 hooks that posts updated rectangles to a manager (sniffing WM_PAINT and related messages).

However, WPF applicatons uses Direct3D surfaces, so listening for windows messages does not help much.

Is there a way to intercept these surfaces, and get dirty rectangles/regions (eg. when a control or other component is redrawn) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no way of achieving this.

My solution in this case is to do frequent BitBlt(), and analyze the differences between current and previous pixel buffers. I then divide the screen into cells with fixed widths/heights, and keep track of changes for each cell.